# while loop giving strange results

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

This while loop works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. can anyone see why?
I feel like it should start looping, and keep looping till the dealers total is greater than 17 and hit the else block. once it goes into the else block it should update the outcome value. however, sometimes it jumps into the else block and then jumps straight to the `console.log(outcome)` and tells me it is undefined.  sometimes it will return the correct outcome. e.g. it outputs 'dealer wins!'
I feel like I have met every condition?
I have even put in console.logs and the line `dealersTotal = total` gets updated correctly. why is it not continuously looping?

```
 dealerTwisted = () => {
    let dealersTotal = this.state.dealersOverallTotal;
    let playersTotal = this.state.playersOverallTotal;
    let looping = true;
    let outcome = '';
    while(looping){
      if(dealersTotal < 17){
        this.deal2Dealer();
        let dealersDeck = this.state.dealersDeck;
        let newDealersDeckTotal = [];
        for (var i=0; i < dealersDeck.length; i++){
          newDealersDeckTotal.push(dealersDeck[i].rankValue)
        }
        let total = newDealersDeckTotal.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a + b;
        },
        0);
        dealersTotal = total;
      }
      else {
        if(dealersTotal > 21){
          outcome = 'player wins!';
          break;
        }
        else if(playersTotal > dealersTotal){
          outcome = 'player wins!'; 
          break;
        }
        else if (playersTotal == dealersTotal){
          outcome = 'tie!';
          break;
        }
        else if (dealersTotal > playersTotal){
          outcome = 'dealer wins!';
          break;
        }
        else {
          console.log('got here');
          break;
        }
      }
      console.log(outcome);
      this.setState({resultOutcome: outcome})
      break;
    }
  };
```

EDIT: Think I have figured it out. It must go into the first if and then it hits the break at the end of the big else. HOWEVER, problem is still that I need it to loop around and only break once all conditions have been covered. solution?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your loop will always have only one iteration because of the unconditional `break` at the end.

Comment: @NikolaNovak you are right so how can I change this to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set looping to false anywhere? I can't see it. If not, try setting looping to false at the end of the big else block.

Example:

```
else {
        if(dealersTotal > 21){
          outcome = 'player wins!';
        }
        else if(playersTotal > dealersTotal){
          outcome = 'player wins!'; 
        }
        else if (playersTotal == dealersTotal){
          outcome = 'tie!';
        }
        else if (dealersTotal > playersTotal){
          outcome = 'dealer wins!';
        }
        else {
          console.log('got here');
        }
        console.log(outcome);
        this.setState({resultOutcome: outcome});
        looping = false;
   }
```

Comment: does breaking not do the same thing?

Comment: You should remove all breaks at the big else as Al. G. suggests, and instead set looping to false once the program should end. (At the end of the big else)

Comment: @Theworm, `break` breaks out of the first enclosing loop immediately, whereas setting `looping = false` will finish the current iteration, then end the loop because loop condition will be `false`. Loop condition is only checked at the start of the iteration in this case.

Comment: Who is "Al. G." @ManuelS.?

Comment: I edited the response with an example, so you can see how it could look. Also read @NikolaNovak 's comment to answer your question about does breaking not do the same thing.

Comment: @JamesMonger he had commented the OP's question. It seems he deleted his comment.

Comment: @Theworm did this answer help you with your questions? If so, mark it as correct, if not, provide further input to know how can we help. If you found the answer yourself, please post it and accept it so others can benefit from it.